# How to convert Pandas data frame to dict with values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a huge Pandas data frame with the structure follows as an example below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'col2': [1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 6]})
df
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    B     5
3    C     2
4    C     4
5    C     6
```

The task is to build a dictionary with elements in `col1` as keys and corresponding elements in `col2` as values. For the example above the output should be:

```
A -> [1, 2]
B -> [5]
C -> [2, 4, 6]
```

Although I write a solution as

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(set)

for row in df.itertuples():
    dd[row.col1].append(row.col2)
```

I wonder if somebody is aware of a more "Python-native" solution, using in-build pandas functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `list` for `Series` of lists and then [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [5], 'C': [2, 4, 6]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Without `apply` we do it by for loop

```
{x : y.tolist() for x , y in df.col2.groupby(df.col1)}
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [5], 'C': [2, 4, 6]}
```